# Keeping wrapper container a certain percentage of body

Tags: html, css

I'm having a tough time keeping my content centered within a certain width on my personal website. I have tried many methods such as setting body to a fix width and my wrapper container to a percentage of that. I have attached a picture of my website here and highlighted where I want my content to be contained in the picture shown

[image: here].

I want my content of my website centered within that highlighted area, while at the same time keeping the background to be the full size of the screen.

I realize this may be a simple question for many, but I have spent all day looking for and trying out different methods to do this with no avail.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.topSection {
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 5px;
}

.mainAbout {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mainAbout h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: arvo, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#leftBrace {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#rightBrace {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.projects {
  height: 864px;
  border: solid 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: #0F1217;
}

.projects h2 {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: arvo, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper">
  <!---- Wrapper Starts Here --->
  <div class="topSection" style="display:block" ;>
    <!---- Name Section Starts Here --->

    <div id="leftBrace" style="display: inline-block" ;>
      <img src="leftbrace.png">
    </div>

    <div class="mainAbout" style="display: inline-block" ;>
      <!--- Main Name and About me Section ---->

      <h1> Benjamin Yan </h1>
      <p> I am a Senior Year Computer Science student at Sacramento State <br> University, California. I strive to become a professional Web Developer. </p>

    </div>
    <!--- End mainAbout --->

    <div id="rightBrace" style="display: inline-block" ;>
      <img src="rightbrace.png">
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--- Wrapper Ends Here --->

  <div class="projects">
    <h2> Projects </h2>
  </div>

  <div class="contact">
  </div>

</div>
<!--- Wrapper Ends Here --->
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share your code (html + css) with us, so we can see what you've done

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `background` you could style `curly-braces` using pseudo selector `:before and :after`, thus it works like font styling, you could use `transform:translate` to center your intro text container, check below codes.

```css
#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}

#box > .cnt {
  width:50%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#box:before {
  content:"{";
  font-size: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:10%;
}

#box:after {
  content: "}";
  font-size: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right:10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="cnt">
    <h1> Benjamin Yan </h1>
      <p> I am a Senior Year Computer Science student at Sacramento State <br> University, California. I strive to become a professional Web Developer. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Benjamin Yan Check above codes, you could make use of pseudo selector for aligning curly braces in your design as a font-styling or image as you planned.

Comment: @Benjamin Yan Accept or up-vote the solution if it align that properly.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `margin: 0 auto;` to your content class. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure add an `inner` class inside each `wrapper` and define your desired width. And need to apply `margin: 0 auto` to the `inner`. I added demo snippet.If u want specific wrapper full width just remove `inner`class that's enough you will get full width. I hope it will help you.

```css
.wrapper { 
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.inner {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you so much! Is it considered 'poor' coding practice to use body basically the same way you used .wrapper?

Comment: Thank you ..see this link https://codepen.io/bharathkumar_sriram/pen/xXVpJv

Comment: This helps a lot...one problem though: If you look at the original picture in my original question I actually want that highlighted yellow container part to be invisible on my site just to keep the content centered there; whilst keeping the background to the edges of the screen. For example, the top grey section and "projects" black background should still extend all the way to the sides of the screen. In other words, I want the container to technically be "invisible" just to keep content centered. Should I be using a container method or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Its very simple use same background color for both wrapper and inner. Or you can remove background color in inner.